# Create one XML docment per row in a table

Tags: sql, xml, for-xml

I have a table and I would like to add an new column to that table with a summary of the columns.

Example
Columns: A,B

Result:

A,B <TOPNODE><A>value of a</A><B>value of a</A><B><Value of b</B></TOPNODE>

I understand that I can build the XML by hand, but is there a way to create the XML using "for XML".

One idea was to first create a document and the extract the separate notes, but is there a way to do it in one step?

Comment: Just for Info: You can add four spaces before the code, then you don't have to encode entities of your xml (and a free line above the first line of code/xml).

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that next time.

Comment: Do you really need to persist the data in a column? You could instead build the XML when needed in a query. Then you don't have to worry about updating the XML whenever a value is updated. It could be done with a trigger but perhaps unnecessary. If you have multiple queries that need this column you could define a view that adds the XML column and use the view instead of the table in your queries.

Comment: Something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/15e8c/2

Comment: Yes, Mikael, just like that. I never thought about queries in columns, as I am normally against it. Perfect! Thanks